# How to decompose an integer into a array of integers

Tags: ruby

Lets say that I have a number of "things", for instance `7`.

But I can store this "things" in groups of maximum "2" units. So I would need to do something like this:

```
7  ---->  [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

The obvious method if to simply make a loop through it

```
def decompose(qty, group_max)
    ret = []

    while qty > 0
        if qty < group_max
            ret.push qty
            qty = 0
        else
            ret.push group_max
            qty -= group_max
        end
    end

    ret

end

decompose 7, 2
```

While this works... it is **not really ellegant**. I was wondering if maybe there is a method in the integer or the array structure that I can use to improve this code.

I find cleaner to do things like

```
myarray.map {|x| ... }
```

and I was wondering if there was something similar that might help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as:

```
 qty = 15    # say
 group_size = 2
 count_of_groups = qty / group_size
 result = [group_size] * count_of_groups
 remaining = qty % group_size
 result += [remaining] if remaining != 0
 result     # [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def decompose(qty, group_max)
  q, r = qty.divmod(group_max)
  (Array.new(q) { group_max }) + (r > 0 ? [r] : [])
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`divmod` anyone?

```
qty = 15    # say
group_size = 2

d, r  = qty.divmod(group_size)
Array.new(d, group_size) << r # => [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Nice use of `divmod`, but your code adds a `0` if there is no remainder.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take advantage of the Array constructor: first paramter the number of elements, second parameter their value.

```
def decompose(qty, group_max)
  result = Array.new(qty / group_max, group_max)
  remainder = qty % group_max
  remainder == 0 ? result : result.push(remainder)
end

decompose(7, 2)
 => [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

A one line solution

```
def decompose(qty, group_max)
  (Array.new(qty / group_max, group_max) + [qty % group_max]).reject(&:zero?)
end
```

Comment: I don't like the last line, probably there's a better way.

Comment: how about? `result.push(remainder) if remainder > 0`

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent this results in function returns `nil` for zero reminder.

Comment: I added a one line solution but I don't know how it looks

Answer (score 2):

```
val, max = 8, 3
([max] * (val / max)).tap do |arr|
  arr << val % max unless (val % max).zero?
end
#⇒ [3, 3, 2]

val, max = 7, 2
([max] * (val / max)).tap do |arr|
  arr << val % max unless (val % max).zero?
end
#⇒ [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

or even:

```
([max] * (val / max) + [val % max]).reject &:zero?
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to skin the cat:

> Lets say that I have a number of "things", for instance 7.

Let's use an array to represent that, each `nil` is a "thing":

```
Array.new(7)
#=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

> But I can store this "things" in groups of maximum "2" units:

[`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) can do that:

```
Array.new(7).each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [[nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil]]
```

To get the number of "things" in each group:

```
Array.new(7).each_slice(2).map(&:length)
#=> [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def decompose(n, grp_size)
  nbr_groups, remainder = n.divmod(grp_size)
  [grp_size]*nbr_groups << remainder
end

decompose(23, 3)
  #=> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: @ScottWeldon, I provided no explanation because I saw no need for one. Should I have spoon-fed the docs for [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod) and [Array#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) to readers unfamiliar with those methods? Beyond that the method is simple. I agree that when an answer is complex, an explanation is called for (see [another of my recent answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528021/compare-array-of-hashes-and-print-expected-actual-results/40539172#40539172)), but when it's not needed it's just fluff.