# compare array of hashes and print expected & actual results

Tags: ruby, hash

I have 2 array of hashes:

```
actual = [{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTINCOME", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
 {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"VARCHAR"},
 {"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"},
 {"column_name"=>"UPDATEDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"}]
expected = [{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTINCOME", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
 {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
 {"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
 {"column_name"=>"UPDATEDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"}]
```

I need to compare these 2 hashes and find out the ones for which the `column_data_type` differs.

to compare we can directly use:

```
diff = actual -   expected
```

This will print the output as:

```
{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"VARCHAR"}
{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"}
```

My expected output is that in the result i want to print the actual and expected datatype, means the datatypes for the missing `column_name' from both the actual and expected array of hashes, something like:

```
{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "expected_column_data_type"=>"NUMBER", "actual_column_data_type" => "VARCHAR"}
{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "expected_column_data_type"=>"NUMBER","actual_column_data_type" => "TIMESTAMP" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(expected - actual).
  concat(actual - expected).
  group_by { |column| column['column_name'] }.
  map do |name, (expected, actual)|
    {
      'column_name'               => name,
      'expected_column_data_type' => expected['column_data_type'],
      'actual_column_data_type'   => actual['column_data_type'],
    }
  end
```

Comment: This requires that for `h = a.group_by {... }`, for any array `a`, the ordering of the elements in each value (array) of `h` must be consistent with their ordering in `a`. While I expect that will be the case, so far as I know it is not guaranteed in the docs.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I see what you mean. A few things here: (1) [the ruby spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/enumerable/group_by_spec.rb) wouldn't work if that wasn't the case, which is officially used by cruby [for some time now](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/spec). (2) the ruby documentation (ruby-doc.org) is not maintained by anyone in the ruby core team. Ruby is defined as what is in Matz' head. (3) The current implementation is optimal. I doubt we will find a better algorithm that also happens to not guarantee order.

Answer (score 1):

This will work irrespective of order of hashes in your array.

```
diff = []

expected.each do |elem|
  column_name = elem['column_name']
  column_type = elem['column_data_type']
  match = actual.detect { |elem2| elem2['column_name'] == column_name  }
  if column_type != match['column_data_type']
    diff << { 'column_name' => column_name,
              'expected_column_data_type' => column_type,
              'actual_column_data_type' => match['column_data_type'] }
  end
end

p diff
```

Comment: Consider using `each_with_object` instead of redundant local variable. It’s ruby, not php.

Answer (score 1):

```
[actual, expected].map { |a| a.map(&:dup).map(&:values) }
                  .map(&Hash.method(:[]))
                  .reduce do |actual, expected|
                    actual.merge(expected) do |k, o, n|
                      o == n ? nil : {name: k, actual: o, expected: n}
                    end
                  end.values.compact

#⇒ [
#    [0] {
#            :name => "NONINTERESTEXPENSE",
#          :actual => "VARCHAR",
#        :expected => "NUMBER"
#    },
#    [1] {
#            :name => "TRANSACTIONDATE",
#          :actual => "TIMESTAMP",
#        :expected => "NUMBER"
#    }
# ]
```

The method above easily expandable to merge N arrays (use `reduce.with_index` and `merge` with key `"value_from_#{idx}"`.)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def select(hashes_array, column_name)
  hashes_array.select { |h| h["column_name"] == column_name }.first
end

diff = (expected - actual).map do |h|
  {
    "column_name" => h["column_name"],
    "expected_column_data_type" => select(expected, h["column_name"])["column_data_type"],
    "actual_column_data_type" => select(actual, h["column_name"])["column_data_type"],
  }
end
```

PS: surely this code can be improved to look more elegant

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def convert(actual, expected)
  hashify(actual-expected, "actual_data_type").
  merge(hashify(expected-actual, "expected_data_type")) { |_,a,e| a.merge(e) }.values
end

def hashify(arr, key)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["column_name"]] =
    { "column_name"=>g["column_name"], key=>g["column_data_type"] } }
end
```

**Example**

```
actual = [
  {"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"},
  {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"VARCHAR"},
  {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTINCOME", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  {"column_name"=>"UPDATEDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"}
]

expected = [
  {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTINCOME", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  {"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  {"column_name"=>"UPDATEDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"}
]

convert(actual, expected)
  #=> [{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE",
  #     "actual_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP", "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  #    {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE",
  #     "actual_data_type"=>"VARCHAR", "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"}]
```

**Explanation**

For the example above the steps are as follows.

First `hashify` `actual` and `expected`.

```
f = actual-expected
  #=> [{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"},
  #    {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"VARCHAR"}]

g = hashify(f, "actual_data_type")
  #=> {"TRANSACTIONDATE"=>{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE",
  #      "actual_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP"},
  #    "NONINTERESTEXPENSE"=>{ "column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE",
  #      "actual_data_type"=>"VARCHAR"}}

h = expected-actual
  #=> [{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  #    {"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "column_data_type"=>"NUMBER"}]

i = hashify(h, "expected_data_type")
  #=> {"NONINTERESTEXPENSE"=>{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE",
  #      "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  #    "TRANSACTIONDATE"=>{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE",
  #      "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"}}
```

Next merge `g` and `i` using the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc  for the definitions of the three block variables (the first of which, the common key, I've represented by an underscore to signify that it is not used in the block calculation).

```
j = g.merge(i) { |_,a,e| a.merge(e) }
  #=> {"TRANSACTIONDATE"=>{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE",
  #      "actual_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP", "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  #    "NONINTERESTEXPENSE"=>{"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE",
  #      "actual_data_type"=>"VARCHAR", "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"}}
```

Lastly, drop the keys.

```
k = j.values
  #=> [{"column_name"=>"TRANSACTIONDATE", "actual_data_type"=>"TIMESTAMP",
  #     "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"},
  #    {"column_name"=>"NONINTERESTEXPENSE", "actual_data_type"=>"VARCHAR",
  #     "expected_data_type"=>"NUMBER"}]
```